# Cross Join with php codeigniter query

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there away to cross join from php.  In example:
Currently I query a database like so:

```
                            $company_id = 20;
  $templates_data = $this->db->select('template_id')
                            ->from('dr_template_relational')
                            ->where('dr_template_relational.company_id',$company_id)
                            ->get()
                            ->result_array();
```

What I'm looking to do is something like this:

```
->from('dr_template_relational')
->cross_join()
```

There's several responses to this question on SO but post reference a regular sql query like so:

```
"SELECT * FROM citys LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.city=citys.city WHERE citys.id=$id";
```

This would be the way to do it in SQL query but the point here is to do it in php and get the data returned with a cross join.  I also realize the query can be made with in php to have it select the data and join it with code but my question is related to is there away to simply add `->cross_join()` or something like that.

Comment: Ah man dumb me, once you said what framework I checked that: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html @PetervanderWal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run raw query in codeigniter to solve your problem as below:

```
$sql 'your query here with cross join';
$query = $this->db->query($sql);

return $query->result_array();
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: I have to admit that I'm unfamiliar with codeigniter, so partly out of curiosity: why do you suggest using this method over `->db->join('...')` as described in the [manual](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)? Writing your query by hand is (imho) more vulnerable for making SQL-injection-errors. I asume `$company_id` isn't hard coded but something that comes from a request or so.

Comment: @PetervanderWal There is no issues using raw query as we can still bind the data variables in that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CI join method.

```
$company_id = 20;
        $templates_data = $this->db->select('dr_template_relational.template_id')
            ->where('dr_template_relational.company_id',$company_id)
            ->join('table','dr_template_relational.company_id=table.company_id','LEFT')
            ->get()
            ->result_array();
```

where 'LEFT' is the join type

Comment: This doesn't accept "CROSS" as a valid join type - valid types are LEFT, RIGHT, OUTER, INNER, LEFT OUTER and RIGHT OUTER [source](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/Database/BaseBuilder.php#L238)